# Is $ds$ and curvature has the max value at the same point?

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

If there is a plane curve, define as a $y=f(x)$, and my guess is if curvature of this curve $\frac{y^{\prime\prime}}{(1+(y\prime^2))^\frac{3}{2}}$ has a max value at ${x=x_0}$ and $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ has the max value at same point. that two is necessity, or sufficiency or both of them, or not anything? I try to derive them and both have $0$at same point, but this method not worked well.

Comment: If you are using that formular, then you are actually using the parametrization $\mathbf {r} (t)=(t,f(t))$. But curvature is intrinsic and doesnt depend on parametrization. Specifically for any regular curve there is always an arclength parametrization where $|r(t)|=1$ at every point

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "$\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ has a maximum value at a point." I presume you mean to write $\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$ has a maximum, which happens at a maximum of $y'$, i.e., at a zero of $y''$. So, no, nothing to do with maximum curvature.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using the parametrization $r(t)=(t,f(t))$

Then the maximum of the speed is at

$$\frac{d^2 s}{dt^2}=\frac{f'(t)f''(t)}{\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}}=0$$

Which would imply that $f'(t)=0$ or $f''(t)=0$, but we reject the case for $f'(t)=0$ because curvature cannot be defined on non regular curve.

So that means the speed is at maximum when the second derivative of the curve is $0$.

$$\kappa '(t)=\frac{f'''(t)(1+f'(t)^2)^{\frac 32} - \frac 32 (1+f'(t)^2)^{\frac 12} (2f'(t)f''(t))f''(t)}{(1+f'(t)^2)^3}$$

It is equal to zero when the numerator is $0$ :

$$f'''(t)(1+f'(t)^2)^2 -3f'(t)f''(t)^2=0$$

If $f''(t)=0$ , we must have $f'''(t)=0$ also in order for the curvature to be at maximum, so we cannot conclude that.

In general, the curvature of a plane curve is an intrinsic property in the sense that it is independent of the parametrization and rigid transformation. So usually there would be no relation between the curvature and the derivative of the curve.

Comment: Downvoter, mind telling what I did wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I actually do is, I do project about analysis the fracture of the glass, I assume glass breaks when it bends more than it’s “critical curvature”. To prove this assumption, I think about another aspect, regard “breaking glass” phenomenon as the distance between atom in a glass get bigger than its possible value, so I try to prove $ds$ (distance between glass atoms) is getting bigger, when curvature $ (t, f (t)) $ at that point is increased. So your answer, it means my assumption is wrong?

Comment: @kyj519 I think this is more of a physics question than a geometry one. Firstly, a curve is more of a "moving" object when equipped with a parametrization. The separation between atoms do not depend on the modelling of the shape, instead it should be related to the density and the bending force applied. Since I am no expert in physics, so again, I suggest you direct this question to physics SE to receive better help.